# ArcEngine 10 Editor:  Split/Rotate/Cut Features toolbar?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-engine, toolbar

I am currently looking for the *Split/Rotate/Cut/Reshape* tools in the toolbar control provided by ESRI, however according to [ArcGIS Engine commands](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//00010000039p000000) page there isn't one.

Is it called something else or does it only exist in ArcEditor?

Answer (score 2):

There are built-in commands available in ArcEngine for rotate: `ControlsRotateLeftCommand`, `ControlsRotateElementTool`, `ControlsRotateRightCommand`.  You are correct, the rest are only supported in ArcMap.  Take a look at [ArcEngine editing](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/ArcGIS_Engine_editing/00010000009v000000/) for the remaining tasks.